# Linux command to display info about NFS mounts

Tags: linux

What is the command in Linux that displays the information about local mount,remote host, remote host source,mount options and owner of the NFS mounts?

Comment: Ask here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for:

```
nfsstat --mounts
```

That will print information regarding each mounted `nfs` file system. You may also be interested in `nfsidmap` and `nfsiostat` which each show a bit more granular information about specific user/group mappings and io statistics.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look for `mount` command

Comment: But that does not give information about owner of NFS mount

Comment: Could you please help me with the proper command which displays all the information I mentioned in the question